# Binary Search a non-existing number in a sorted array, return a larger negative number than -1

Tags: arrays

When the search number is 12, why does it return -6 instead of -1?

```java
int[] list = {2, 4, 7, 10, 11, 45, 50, 59, 60, 66, 69, 70, 79};
System.out.println("1. Index is " + Arrays.binarySearch(list, 11));
System.out.println("2. Index is " + Arrays.binarySearch(list, 12));
```

```html
Result:
1. Index is 4
2. Index is -6
```

#### Update

Now I understand because
Arrays.binarySearch will return

```java
(-(insertion point) - 1)
```

if the number is not in the array.
i.e
12 is at insertion of 5, so return (-(5) - 1) = -6.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/, i.e. **reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may refer to the Javadoc : [`Arrays.binarySearch(int[] a,int key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-)

It returns :

- `index of the search key`, if it is contained in the array;
- otherwise : (`-(insertion point) - 1`).

---

Here the insertion point would be :

```
int[] list = {2, 4, 7, 10, 11, 45, 50, 59, 60, 66, 69, 70, 79};
         //  1^ 2^ 3^  4^  5^
```

The position `5` so `(-5-1) = -6`

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from [BinarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(float[],%20float))

*Return value:*

*This method returns index of the search key, if it is contained in the array, else it returns (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index of the first element greater than the key, or a.length if all elements in the array are less than the specified key.*

From the return value explanation, it returns the negation of the position the element will be in the array (that is -5) minus 1, which would be -6.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common return type for `BinarySearch()` methods. 
If you would like to print the index of an integer `a` :

```
int[] list = {2, 4, 7, 10, 11, 45, 50, 59, 60, 66, 69, 70, 79};
int a =12; //Value can be updated or read through Scanner
int temp = Arrays.binarySearch(list,a);
if(temp>=0){ 
     System.out.println("Index of a is : " + temp)
}else{
     System.out.println("Insertion point for a is : " + (-1)*(temp+1);
}
```